# Make calls using telnet from one Android Emulator to another?

Tags: android, android-emulator, telnet, phone-call

Is it possible to make calls through telnet from one Android Emulator to another?

For example, I have two emulators 5554 and 5556 open on the screen. I can use the command: `gsm call 5554` to get an incoming call from 5554 through telnet.

Is it possible to make an outgoing call from 5554 to 5556 or vice-versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
USe the following stps:

1. Start both the emulators (e.g., 5556 and 5558)
2. On windows go to start; type cmd; and type telnet localhost 5556 and you will get 
   connected to the emulator which is on port 5556
3. Now type gsm call 5556
4. Receive the call on the emulator 5556 by clicking/drawing the green phone to the right side.
5. Click the add call button with + sign on the emulator 5556 screen.
6. On the dial pad dial the number 5558 and click the green phone icon. You will listen that it is ringing to the other emulator 5558.
7. On the emulator 5558, you will see after some time incoming call notification. Receive the call by clicking it and clicking the phone icon and the green phone icon. Notice that 5556 is on hold which is the call from the telnet.
8. Press the swap button on 5556 emulator screen and now 5558 emulator is on hold and telent call which is using the number 5556 is on line.
9. Now when 5558 is on hold. Click the red phone icon on the 5556 emulator screen which will cancel the call between the telnet and 5556 emulator but the call between the two emulators remian.
10. Cancel the call on 5558 emulator now. The call ends.
11. Now dial the emulator 5556 from 5558 by clicking the number in the call log shown on the top of the screen OR do it from the other emulator 5556 and they are on line with one another.

[You can see the screenshots on the URL below:](http://android.codopedia.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much...
Finally someone took the trouble to answer.
Your suggestion works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way - use dialer.

Use port number as a phone number to place a call from one emulator to another.